# Importing the Apache Solr data using Cron Jobs

Tags: apache, indexing, solr, cron, data-import

I have installed and configured Apache Solr in Ubuntu 16 and it is working fine and when I import the data from the Apache Solr web console by accessing the Solr from http://localhost:8983. Now I'm trying to import the data every 15 or 30 min, which means I want to do indexing for every 15 or 30 min using a `cron` job in Linux

Below is the URL that I have configured the crontab

```sh
wget -O -q http://username:password@localhost:8983/solr/collection1/dataimport?command=full-import
```

When the `cron` job runs, I was able to get the data, but sometimes I was not able to index the data using my `cron` job and it is failing

Did I write the `cron` job correctly or for data importing or indexing I need to use `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: There are many logs to look at: cron logs to confirm it is indeed running.  In your crontab, add `>/tmp/out1 2>/tmp/out2` to your command.  Then you can review these log files to see if the crontab execution send something.  Also check the mail of the user running this cron.  Output from cron will be sent there.  There is no problem doing what you do, I do the same on my SOLR (once a day for me).  And lastly check your SOLR logs to confirm it did do the indexing.   And remember if your dataimport is heavy in processing your queries might suffer.

Comment: what do logs say?

Comment: I haven't tested, I will test today and will you give an update...

Comment: I have tried another way and it worked